# Network error when configuring tezos-client

Tags: tezos-client

I was following instructions on https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/1-tezos-client/ to install on MacOS, but following command:

`tezos-client --endpoint https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net config update` is constantly giving following error:

```
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  The request has timed out
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a public node endpoint. You can get one here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/rpc_nodes
For instance: `tezos-client --endpoint https://mainnet.api.tez.ie config update`